# call partialRefreshGet from SSJS using view.PostScript

Tags: xpages, client-side, xpages-ssjs

I have a SSJS running in the BeforePageKoad event. As the last step of the SSJS I want to do a partial refresh. In my script I have this line of code:

```
view.postScript("partialRefreshGet('#{id:panelAll}')")
```

When it executes I get an error that says partialRefreshGet is undeffined. I'm guessing I'm missing something in the format of the call, but as I understand it this should work.
Anyone done something like this before. 
If I leave this code out then do a manual refresh of panelAll from a button everything works correctly.

Comment: I'm curious why you would do a partial refresh on initial page load. Presumably everything would just recalculate to the same value during the partial refresh as it does on the initial load, since the user hasn't had an opportunity to interact with the page yet. Can you provide more information about your use case?

Comment: My code gets a "profile" document then populates a bunch of controls with the values from the control. I load the values into the NotesDocument and perhaps should have used the dataSource, but it works fine except for the refresh. I have a button on the XPage that simply does a partial refresh and then everything is good. The code only executes if it is a new document.

Answer (score 4):

You can't use before view.postScript in the beforePageLoad.   Try moving it to afterPageLoad or beforeRenderResponse.   I recently ran across the same issue.

http://notesspeak.blogspot.com/2013/08/viewpostscript-only-works-for-certain.html

Here is a summary where you can use view.postScript():

1. onClientLoad = nothing happens
2. beforePageLoad = XSP error
3. afterPageLoad = WORKS!
4. afterRestoreView = nothing happens
5. beforeRenderResponse = WORKS!
6. afterRenderResponse = nothing happens

To know why this is happening, read Tim Tripcony's comment at the bottom of the blog post.

Comment: I added it to the beforeRenderResponse and I get the same error so I'm guessing there is something wrong with the syntax or ???

Comment: The view.postScript part seems to be working but it does not recognize the partialRefreshGet and says that it is undefined.

Comment: Bill, the contents of the view.postScript are clientside code.  It looks like your code doesn't have the semi-colon which is required there.  Also, the ID's are changed by the server, they look like "view:_id1:..."  Check Firebug, and copy your code to the console and see what you get.

Comment: Also, you don't want to ever hardcode using the generated ID's ('view:_id1:...")  If you must use them, then uses Mark Roden's x$ function found on xomino.com

Comment: After looking up the partialRefreshGet method which I haven't used, it looks like you can use the id that you could in SSJS according to xpageswiki.com.   You do need to preface it by "XSP" which is probably the cause of the "undefined"

Comment: I added this to the beforeRenderResponse -> view.postScript("XSP.partialRefreshGet('#{id:panelAll}')") I do not get an error but it does not appear to do the partial refresh. Once the document displays I still have to click the refresh button that does a partial refresh on panelAll. So I'm at a loss.

Comment: Most likely it's attempting to run the code too soon and should be wrapped in a `XSP.addOnLoad()`; see Sven's answer for the correct syntax.

Comment: I noticed that you are still missing the semi-colon, but nevertheless I also think you give Sven's solution a try.  You then aren't restricted to the limitations of view.postScript.

Answer (score 3):

Just add a scriptblock to your XPage with the required partial refresh.

**EDIT:**

```
<xp:scriptBlock id="scriptBlock2" rendered="#{javascript:requestScope.doRefresh}">
    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[
       XSP.addOnLoad( function(){ XSP.partialRefreshGet('#{id:panelAll}') } );
   ]]>
   </xp:this.value>
</xp:scriptBlock>
```

In your *beforePageLoad* you then set the requestScope variable if required.

Comment: I added this and the refresh does not seem to happen. I changed the XSP.addOnLoad to just do a viewScope.put and the code is being executed. So this addOnLoad should happen after the beforePageLoad so it should have all the values set in the beforePageLoad. In the beforePageLoad I and modifying the NotesDocument not the dataSource but I don't think this should matter. The partialRefresh on a button once the page is loaded properly refreshes all the controls. I'm guessing it is a timing issue but I kind of lost. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @BillF: It seems to me that there is a misunderstanding beteeen clientside and serverside code. The other problem is that  changing the document instead of the datasource matters, and that is why your code is not working.

Answer (score 1):

This answer might be a little too late, I hope it would be useful for someone.

So, the simple answer is to use the following SSJS to refresh another component:
`view.postScript("XSP.partialRefreshGet('#{id:`*`Component ID`*`}')")`

However, I've had my share of trouble trying it, and as Tim Tripcony suggested, the code seems to be running too soon, while the browser is still receiving the 1st refresh, and it doesn't work. So I tried attaching it in an OnLoad event like so:

`view.postScript("XSP.addOnLoad(function() {XSP.partialRefreshGet('#{id:`*`Component ID`*`}')})")`

But that also didn't work. So I did it the old way and it worked by letting the script work in a different thread using *setTimeout()* like this:

`view.postScript("setTimeout(function(){XSP.partialRefreshGet('#{id:`*`Component ID`*`}')}, 1)");`

and it's working like a charm!

Comment: Actually, I'm personally using the partialRefreshPost() function, rather than Get, but I've included it as Get in this answer for the sake of the asker's logic; and I don't think that this difference would affect the validity of the answer.